# How to send servlet response with hardcoded html page?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'd like to response to a url request with a hardcoded but dynamic html response.

Are there better ways than doing following way?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Hola</title>");
    //
}
```

?

Comment: you basically have to send the HTML to document i.e do `document.write(yourHTMLThatIsGenratedDynamically)` don't matter how you do it..

Comment: This way is OK for simple case. But how big is your dynamic part? Why to not use JSP, if you have a lot of UI related logic on your page.

Comment: But that would be JS? I want to response with the webpage from a servlet doGet/doPost request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is just to forward the response in your servlet:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("mypage.html").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "a hardcoded but dynamic html response."

If you mean that you have some number of existing HTML files, and want to pick one based on request parameters, then your servlet can use [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to load the files. You'll need to package the files on the classpath, which is easy if you use a tool like Maven,  little more difficult with a tool like Ant, and hard to maintain if you're just making builds from Eclipse or the command line.

If you mean that you have a single template file and want to change the content in some way, use [JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro.html#wp100465).